# Find replace using regular expression to keep what is in brackets

Tags: regex, visual-studio, replace

Given I have 1000's of...

```
LegacyProject.LegacyNameSpace.LegacyClass.LegacyMethod("blah");

...

LegacyProject.LegacyNameSpace.LegacyClass.LegacyMethod("foo");

...

LegacyProject.LegacyNameSpace.LegacyClass.LegacyMethod("and so on...");
```

Is there a way I can find and replace them perhaps by regex? In order to keep the string parameter to get the following examples...

```
NewMethod(LegacyProject.LegacyNameSpace.LegacyClass.LegacyMethod("blah"));
NewMethod(LegacyProject.LegacyNameSpace.LegacyClass.LegacyMethod("foo"));
NewMethod(LegacyProject.LegacyNameSpace.LegacyClass.LegacyMethod("and so on"));
```

I cannot change the original method as it is abstracted away unfortunately and is always located in a view (.cshtml) file.

EDIT: To the buffoon who thinks this needs more focus... A regex to turn example strings 1 into example strings 2 is what I am after. I despair with the pedants on here...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the following regex the first, and only, capturing group can be used using
$1 or \1 depending on the flavour of regex.

```
^LegacyProject.LegacyNameSpace.LegacyClass.LegacyMethod\("(.*)"\);$
```

in pseudo code we would write

```
link = replace(
           '^LegacyProject.LegacyNameSpace.LegacyClass.LegacyMethod\("(.*)"\);$',
           'NewMethod(LegacyProject.LegacyNameSpace.LegacyClass.LegacyMethod("$1"));',
            link
            )
```

to modifiy according to the flavour of regex that you are using.